# Is it correct to use a v-model's value as the condition of an if-statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, if-statement, v-model

How do I put the `v-model="item.checked"` as the condition of the `if` in below `validations()`?

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) of $v.timesheet.items.$each.$iter" >
        <div>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    v-model="item.checked" 
                    v-on:click="disable(i)"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    :id="'total_hour-' + i"
                />
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div>
            <td>
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
                    @click="itemCount++"
                >Add Row
                </button>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script>
    import { required, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                itemCount: 1,
                timesheet: { items: [{ total_hour: "", checked: false }] },
            }
        },
        methods: {            
            disable(index){
                const check = 
                        document.getElementById('total_hour-' + index).disabled
                $('#total_hour-' + index).attr('disabled', !check);
            }
        },
        watch: {
            itemCount(value, oldValue) {
                if (value > oldValue) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < value - oldValue; i++) {
                        this.timesheet.items.push({
                            total_hour: "",
                            checked: false,
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    this.timesheet.items.splice(value);
                }
            }
        },
        validations() {
            if (  ?  ) {
                return {
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { total_hour: {required} }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { total_hour: {} }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using DOM methods with Vue, you're usually doing it wrong. I think what you want is `:disabled="item.checked"` on your text input

Comment: @Phil, how do I pass the changing state/value to my ```validations()```, Sir?

Comment: Is this correct ```disabled= !disabled```?

Comment: Is there some code missing? I guess you iterate through the timesheet items, do you?

Comment: @tho-masn, thank you for your response. You are right, I am iterating the timesheets items. Already modified my code to include the missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I understand, you want `total_hour` to be a required field only if `checked` is true. Vuelidate provides a nice built-in validator for this purpose called `requiredIf`. It is a [contextified validator](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-contextified-validators) so you can reference a sibling property.

```js
import { required, requiredIf, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

export default {
  ...
  validations: {
    timesheet: {
      items: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(1),
        $each: {
          total_hour: {
            required: requiredIf('checked'),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Another problem I see in your code is that you're trying to iterate over $v fields. $v fields are used to get validation states for your fields, you're not supposed to set $v fields. Using them as `v-model` for components will make vue set the $v fields. Try this:

```
<tr v-for="(item, i) in timesheet.items">
```

Comment: Pardon, Sir @Mythos how do fix it when I do this kind of validation, I noticed that the checked row is required, but it will also toggles the next added row besides of making the previous row (unchecked) behave oppositely where at some points, they altogether are asynchronously affected by every sequence of checking and unchecking. The same goes with changing it to ``requiredUnless`` and re-define the ``checked`` to 'false'. I think there is something else I am missing here... maybe I still need to pass the index ``i`` to my validation, Sir?

Comment: Is it the same if I add the colon to my model from ``checked="checked"`` to ``:checked="checked"``?

Comment: The problem with your code I see is, you're iterating over $v fields. You're not supposed to use $v validation fields as v-model. Try iterating over `timesheet.items`. Vuelidate will handle the rest automatically.

Comment: Sir, I am so sorry if this is troublesome. I modified here and there of my code after changing the iteration to this new format. I have also taken some notes here about how important it is to start the iteration like this and not like what I have started. But... if feasible, for now I need to stick to it just for the meantime as I see there are lot more of modification at other parts needed than what I have already done. Does it is really not possible if I want to figure another way of staying around?

Comment: Well you can use $model for v-model if you're iterating over $v values. Check out this sandbox and tell me if solves your problems: https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-merkle-0u4jg?codemirror=1

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a few things to improve your code.

**Replace watcher with a method**

Watchers are pretty hard to debug and can cause side effects. They should be only used when really necessary.
Instead, create a method, which adds a row:

```
addRow() {
  this.timesheet.items.push({
    total_hour: "",
    checked: false,
  })
}
```

For removing a row, do the same. Just create a method.

**Create a component for each entry**

By creating subComponents for timesheet items, you can handle validation easier and you can react on changes to individual entries better.

```
<table>
  <TimesheetItemRow
    v-for="(item) of $v.timesheet.items.$each.$iter"
    :item="item"
  />
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

To keep track of all the timesheet items in the parent component, you probably want to emit an event from the child component to the parent, containing the new entries data.

**Don't use jQuery or JavaScript Code to manipulate DOM**

Same as before, such things should be used only in super, super edge cases. One of the benefit of Frontend Frameworks like Vue.js is, that you don't need to do this.

Now, that you have a component for each entry, it's easy to handle disabling your input directly in the template

This is some (untested) code for the timesheet item component:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="item.checked
        @click="onClickCheckbox"
      />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        @input="onUpdateTotalHour"
        :disabled="!item.checked
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

  export default {
    props: {
      item: {
        type: Object
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onClickCheckbox (value) {
        this.$emit('on-click-checkbox', value)
      },

      onUpdateTotalHour (value) {
        this.$emit('on-update-total-hour', value)
      }
    },

    validations () {
      if (this.item.checked) {
        return {
          item: {
            total_hour: { required }
          }
        }
      }

      return {
        item: {
          total_hour: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The parent component needs to keep track of all the items, and needs to react on the emitted events.

Comment: thank you for your elaboration. greatly appreciated. but somehow, it triggered an error on loading and this is what appears on my console: ``[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.item is undefined"``. Is it something related to the ``validations()``?

Comment: Do you pass down the item to the subComponent? Maybe you can create a Codesandbox or Stackblitz?