# How to toggle the 'required' validation using if-else

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

I have a `description` input field which I want to make it as **non-required** by checking the checkbox (while unchecking it will do the vice versa).

Here are what I have done:

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) of $v.timesheet.items.$each.$iter">
        <td>
            <input type= "checkbox" v-on:click= "check(i)" status="status">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                            
        <td>
            <button type="button" @click="itemCount++">Add Item</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
<script>
    import { required, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";    
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                status: false,
                itemCount: 1,
                timesheet: { items: [{description: ""}] }
            }
        },
        validations() {
            if (this.status == false) {
                return{
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { description: { required }},
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return{
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { description: { }}
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        },
        watch: {
            itemCount(value, oldValue) {
                if (value == oldValue) {
                    return;
                }
                if (value > oldValue) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < value - oldValue; i++) {
                        this.timesheet.items.push({
                            description: ""
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    this.timesheet.items.splice(value);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: { 
            check(index){
                this.status = !this.status;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This toggles all rows at once instead of working at the only intended individual row.

How do I fix the toggling so that it works just at that specific row?

Comment: Why did you post the same question again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to use a v-model's value as the condition of an if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081312/is-it-correct-to-use-a-v-models-value-as-the-condition-of-an-if-statement)

Comment: Sir @cloned, my apology for this, newbie I am. May I ask for how I should do it better, Sir?

Comment: By using semantic html. Use flexbox to put elements next to each other.

Comment: You are only storing one status in your `data()`. You might need a separate status for each `timesheets.item`.

Comment: @ksav, how do I do that, Sir? I tried with v-model but it does not work with my iteration.

Comment: Did you check the linked answer from @Mythos?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track a value per row, then that value needs to be kept with each individual item that is rendering the row.

Then, if you pass the event and the index (or a unique id), you can update your data in the method with the new value.

```
   <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <h1>Result</h1>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(person, i) in persons" :key="i">
            <label
              >name:
              <input :value="person.name" @change="changeName($event, i)" />
            </label>
            <label>
              status:
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                :checked="person.status"
                @change="check($event, i)"
              />
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      data() {
        return {
          persons: [
            { name: "Karl", status: false },
            { name: "Irma", status: true },
            { name: "David", status: false },
          ],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        check(event, index) {
          this.persons[index].status = event.target.value === "on";
        },
        changeName(event, index) {
          this.persons[index].name = event.target.value;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

[image: Edit summer-leaf-d7zi4]

Comment: I need to say this kind of structure is way better and much readable than mine, Sir @ksav

Comment: Sir @ksav, what do I do with the ``validations()``?

Comment: That's probably outside the scope of this question. Consider asking a new question about validations (with a working example  ).